# Changing Router Name based on condition

Tags: vue.js

I would like to change the router name based on condition.In the following code i am duplicating all the line expect for name.i would like to have one router link with different name based on the path condition.

```
<router-link v-if="path === 'student'"
                    :to="{
                      name: 'studentPage',
                      params: { id: id },
                      }">  
  </router-link>
  <router-link v-else"
                    :to="{
                      name: 'staffPage',
                      params: { id: id },
                      }">  
   </router-link>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<router-link
     :to="{
          name: (path === 'student')?'studentPage':'staffPage',
          params: { id: id },
     }"
>  
</router-link>
```